# Find subdirectory and remove files not containing a specific string LINUX

Tags: linux, directory, find, subdirectory

Given a main path `./class` and within `class` are subdirectories `student1`,`student2`,`student3`...`student100.` within these subdirectories are other sub-directories `history`,`geography`,`Math`. Each of these subdirectories have hundreds of files in them. I want to KEEP all files that have a string `pass` in `Math` ONLY without affecting files in other subjects. So far I can `cd` to `Math` and do this:

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs --null grep -Z -L 'pass' | xargs --null rm`

But it is ineffective to `cd` to `Math`in each of the`100 subdirectories` and `rm` `unwanted` files.

How can one grep only `Math`and execute the code above?

Comment: maybe something like this(untested)? find . -type f | grep -w Math | xargs grep -lvw pass | xargs rm

Comment: @BjornA. this cleans everything in 'Math'

Comment: OK, my bad. I haven't understood the question, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following should do the trick

```
for i in `find . -type d -name *Math* -exec find {} -type f -not -name *pass* \;`; do rm $i ; done
```

Comment: this does the trick in `Math` but it also deletes all other files in `History` etc. I want to keep the files in other subjects. Thanks

Comment: if we put asterix around `*Math*` then the code works. Thanks a lot for providing a solution. This works like a charm.